# The iris tutorial in tensorflow's website does not work well

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, iris-recognition

The code is showed below,and the wrong message is also showed below:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import urllib.request

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TRAINING_URL = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv"

IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"
IRIS_TEST_RRL = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_test.csv"

if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TRAINING):
    raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TRAINING_URL).read()
    with open(IRIS_TRAINING, 'w') as f:
        f.write(raw)

if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TEST):
    raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TEST_RRL).read()
    with open(IRIS_TEST, 'w') as f:
        f.write(raw)

# load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header(
    filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header(
    filename=IRIS_TEST,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32
)

# Specify that all features have real_valued data
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=4)]

# Build 3 layers DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[10, 20, 30],
                                            n_class=3,
                                            model_dir="/tem/iris_model")

# Define the training imputs
def get_train_inputs():
    x = tf.constant(training_set.data)
    y = tf.constant(training_set.target)

    return x, y

# Fit model
classifier.fit(input_fn=get_train_inputs(), steps=2000)

# Define the test inputs
def get_test_inputs():
    x = tf.constant(test_set.data)
    y = tf.constant(test_set.target)

    return x, y

# Evaluate accuracy
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=get_test_inputs(), steps=1)["accuracy"]
print("\nTest Accuracy: {0:f}\n".format(accuracy_score))
```

This prints the following stack-trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/skyfacon/PycharmProjects/LinearFitting/IrisClassification.py", line 35, in <module>
    features_dtype=np.float32
  File "/home/skyfacon/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 69, in load_csv_without_header
    data.append(np.asarray(row, dtype=features_dtype))
  File "/home/skyfacon/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'setosa'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I can not add pictures...upset

Comment: Then copy and paste the error message along with the code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice

Comment: Can you also link the tutorial you are following?

Comment: [The link here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn)

Comment: Yes, I am using the same page and wrote the answer to describe the differences between your code and the code on that link.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, and I am also a newbee to machine learning, thanks for your help, really.

Comment: So, is the problem solved?

Comment: Ｉam afraid not.My tf version is 1.1.0, I do not think it matters

Comment: See, I am using the same url page you gave and running and eveything is working correctly. So in my opinion it matters. I have tensorflow v 1.2.0 . Also can you update the post with the latest code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know which page you are using as tutorial for this. Because the first page which comes when searching in google is this:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn

And the difference between this and what you posted is `tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header` and `tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header`.

The actual URL or iris data you have specified contains the header. And you are trying to load it as a file without the header. Hence the strings in the header are not able to get converted to float and the error.

Change your code to:

```
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TEST,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: Here is the stack-trace:                                                                Traceback (most recent call last):  File"/home/skyfacon/PycharmProjects/LinearFitting/IrisClassification.py", line 31, in <module> features_dtype=np.float32)
  File "/home/skyfacon/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 47, in load_csv_with_header
    header = next(data_file)
StopIteration

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @skyfacon Which version of tensorflow are you using? Try upgrading to latest one before using it to see if that works for you. Its working for me fine.